# If I have a cast in a where clause before I check another field first will it fail?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a scenario where I am aggregating data between two systems.  Unfortunately I am using a table adapter in Visual Studio.

```
  Select * from prsnpsht where Cast(snp_check as bigint) > 10 and sourcereference Is Null
Union ALL
  Select * from prsnpsht where sourcereference is not null
```

In the case above, the snp_check from the first system will be all numeric which will cast with the snp_check to bigint correctly and we know the data is from the first system because the sourcereference is null.  The second system can have other characters in the snp_check field and when it tried to cast to bigint, it fails.

If I keep the structure of the query the way it is, will it attempt to cast all of the checks to big int before it analyzes the sourcereference condition, or is SQL Server smart enough to know that it should limit the data before it tries to cast the snp_check field?

I apologize in advance if this is a duplicate question, but I was unable to find it if it was answered before.

Comment: I don't see "two systems" referenced in your query.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I suspect the question is about logic short circuiting, though the query could be rewritten to avoid that concern.

Comment: We have two systems that write to the same table.  The field snp_check is an nvarchar(25) which allows for both.  The query is for a report.

Comment: I don't understand why you can't just set up a quick test, run the statements, and see for yourself if it works or not. SELECT is not in any way destructive, so it can never hurt to actually test it.

Answer (score 0):

I speculate that for this query:

```
Select *
from prsnpsht
where Cast(snp_check as bigint) > 10 and sourcereference Is Null;
```

You are getting a conversion error.

In SQL Server 2012+, the solution is to use `try_convert()`:

```
Select *
from prsnpsht
where try_convert(bigint, snp_check) > 10 and sourcereference Is Null;
```

In earlier versions, use a `case`:

```
Select *
from prsnpsht
where (case when snp_check not like '%[^0-9]%'
            then convert(bigint, snp_check)
       end) > 10 and
      sourcereference Is Null;
```

Comment: If I exclude the sourcereference from this query and I use the 'try_convert(bigint, snp_check) >  10 - will it also return the results of the snp_check that have alpha characters?

Comment: try_convert returns null when not able to convert: null > 10 = false

Comment: @JohnJanssen . . . No.  `try_convert()` returns `NULL` in that case and the comparison to `> 10` fails.

Answer (score 0):

IF the SQL Server Version is 2012 or above try the following query

```
Select * from prsnpsht where try_convert(bigint,snp_check) > 10 and sourcereference Is Null
Union ALL
  Select * from prsnpsht where sourcereference is not null
```

Try_Convert() returns a `null` value when `snp_check` is an invalid Bigint data